# The Jacobson radical of an algebra contains every maximal $A$-submodule of an $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra over the field $F$. For an $A$-module define $\mathcal A(V) = \{ a \in A \mid Va = 0 \}$, the annihilator of $V$. Denote by $\mathcal M(A)$ a set which contains one isomorphic copy of each irreducible $A$-module. Define
$$
 J(A) = \bigcap_{M \in \mathcal M(A)} \mathcal A(M).
$$
This is called the *Jacobson radical* of $A$. Then

> If $V$ is an $A$-module, then $VJ(A)$ is contained in every maximal submodule of $V$.

If $M$ is a maximal $A$-submodule of $V$, then $V / M$ is simple, hence $(V/M)J(A) = 0$. But I want to show that the homomorphic image of $VJ(A)$  in the quotient is mapped to $0$. Do we have $(VJ(A) + M)/M \le (V/M)J(A)$? And if this does not hold, how to show that $J(A)$ is contained in every maximal $A$-submodule of $V$?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in the definition of the annihilator! Also I made a mistake, I meant $VJ(A)$, not $J(A)$ alone. Thanks for pointing out! Is it now clearer?

Comment: Isn't $(V/M)J(A)=(VJ(A)+M)/M$? And since this equals $0$ don't we get $VJ(A)\subseteq M$?

Comment: That what I am asking. Is it obvious?

Comment: Yes, it is. (If multiply the residue classes modulo $M$ by something you get residue classes of the products.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/alpha-m-n-alpha-m-n-n

Comment: Okay, then it is clear now. Thanks!